# Work easily on a sound file

Tags: c++, audio

I'd like to do some tests in C++ with some sound file (16 bit, mono, 44khz)

```
for (int i = 0; i++, i < lengthofthesoundfile)
{
  mysound[i] ...
}
```

How to convert a WAV file to RAW data only (get rid of the metadatas, etc.) so that I can easily open it in C++ ?

Would someone have a minimal working example of how to load such a file, and then doing a loop on the soundfile's raw data like above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not use, eg, libsndfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.wav` file is simply a [RIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format) file of type `WAVE`, with (at least) the `fmt`  and `data` chunks. The `fmt`  chunk contains information about the format of the `data` chunk, which contains the raw data.

So if you want, you can extract just the `data` chunk for your usage. The RIFF format is really simple (read the Wikipedia page I linked). You should not have any trouble extracting the `data` chunk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information. Would you have a minimal example in C++ showing how to open a 16bit mono 44.1 khz WAV file, and to make a loop on the raw data? Thanks a lot in advance!